# Bubblesort passes >1 not working?

Tags: python

I have the following program in Python for bubble sort which takes as input the number of passes and a unsorted list:

```
def bubblesort(passnum,list=[]):
    for j in range (passnum):
        for i in range (len(list)):
            if list[i-1]<list[i]:
                continue
            elif list[i-1]>list[i]:
                temp=list[i]
                list[i]=list[i-1]
                list[i-1]=temp

list=[54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
passnum=int(input("Enter the number of passes\n"))
bubblesort(passnum,list)
print(list)
```

But it is sorting the list on first pass but not working on subsequent passes. Can someone tell what's wrong, since i am still a beginner in Python?

I get the output:

```
Enter the number of passes: 2 
[54,17,77,31,44,55,20,26,93]
```

Which means the first pass ran correctly because of 93 at highest index, but then 77 should be before 93.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument You also shouldn't be using `list` as a name because that is a builtin

Comment: @roagnjosh, that an enhancement, since i am a beginner, i am not working on enhancements, but on functions, therefore if you can kindly suggest why this function is not sorting on higher number passes.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "enhancement"? The link I posted is in reference to a mutable default argument, and you're also trampling on a builtin name. Your code doesn't work; do you not think it's worth considering whether these "enhancements" might be part of the solution to your problem?

Comment: Or, put another way, your comment amounts to "I want to code badly and still get the correct result". Please do not approach learning programming like this.

Comment: tell us what results do you get and what they should be in your opinion and why or it is an off-topic question, we are not here to decrypt your code and intentions

Comment: @Azat Ibarkov i get the output:
Enter the number of passes:
2
[54,17,77,31,44,55,20,26,93]
Which means the first pass ran correctly because of 93 at highest index, but then 55 should be with 93.

Answer (score 1):

First of all as @roganjosh said

- we should avoid setting default argument to a mutable object (only if it was our intent to do so, e.g. for some kind of caching), furthermore this default value is never used, running `sort` with default empty container doesn't make sense when we can explicitly pass empty `list` if we need, so we can simply delete default argument here,
- we should avoid re-using built-ins names (it ends up in unpredictable behavior).

Also swap in `Python` can be done without `temp` object using `tuple`s.

About your problem: `range` built-in function with single argument generates `int` objects from `0` to `argument - 1`, so in your particular case on first iteration (`i = 0`) you are comparing

```
list[-1] < list[0]
```

which turns to be `False` on the second pass (because last element is the `max` element), so we are replacing first and last element.

So we can end up with something like

```
def bubblesort(passnum, list_):
    for _ in range(passnum):
        for i in range(1, len(list_)):  # note that we are starting from 1 instead of 0
            if list_[i - 1] < list_[i]:
                continue
            elif list_[i - 1] > list_[i]:
                list_[i], list_[i - 1] = list_[i - 1], list_[i]
```

## Test

```
>>> list_ = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
>>> passnum = int(input("Enter the number of passes\n"))
Enter the number of passes
2
>>> bubblesort(passnum, list_)
>>> list_
[26, 17, 54, 31, 44, 55, 20, 77, 93]
```

## Further reading

- [`range` built-in docs](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-range).